# Screen resolution settings menu disappeared

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, display-resolution

For some reason, I cannot edit screen resolution from the system settings menu. I have to do it with xrandr from the terminal, which is inconvenient for an eternally casual Linux user such as myself. Does anybody have an idea of what might be going wrong here? I tried doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` [like this extremely old Linux forum post suggests](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/missing-screen-resolution-548596/), but predictably it didn't work.

I am running Kubuntu 18.04

edit: Here is the output of `xrandr` (my screen's resolution is 1920x1080 for the record):

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: I edited my original post with the output of `xrandr`
Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.